# React JS: Is it possible to use a helper function without importing it?

Tags: reactjs, helper

Can I define a function globally in one file (e.g. helper.js somewhere) to use this function without importing it in every component file?

Comment: Well, you could put it on the window object, but i'd recommend using imports unless you have a really good reason not to.

Answer (score 0):

As @nicholas-tower said :

> You could put it on the window object, but i'd recommend using imports unless you have a really good reason not to.

If want to improve your workflow and not having to write same things for every components :
**Use snippets**.

---

If you're working with VS Code, here the documentation on [how to create your own](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_create-your-own-snippets).

- Go on the `Code` menu (`File`if you're not a Mac user) -> `Preferences` -> `Configure User Snippets`.
- The fast access field open and you have to select the language, for this it will be `javascriptreact` (JavaScript JSX).
- It will open the *javascriptreact.json* file, and you can add you snippet here.

E.G :

```json
    "Component with helper": {
        "prefix": "cwhlp",
        "body": [
            "import React, { useEffect } from 'react'",
            "import { helper }from '/src/utils/helper'",
            " ",
            "const ${1:ComponentName} = props => {",
            "  useEffect(() => {",
            "    helper();",
            "  }, [])",
            " ",
            "  return (",
            "    $0",
            "  )",
            "}",
            " ",
            " ",
            "export default ${1:ComponentName}"
        ]
    }
```

With this snippet, just with `cwhlp` you will obtain :

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { helper } from "/src/utils/helper";

const ComponentName = props => {
    useEffect(() => {
        helper();
    }, []);

    return <h1></h1>;
};

export default ComponentName;
```

Enter the `ComponentName` will complete automatically everywhere there is a `${1:ComponentName}`.

---

You also can add your snippets in a `name-as-want.code-snippets` in your project directory :

- They will be specific to this project.
- They can be easily shared.

You will have to specify the language :

```json
{
  "javascriptreact" : {
    "Component with helper" : {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```